# How to write truffle migration file for the contract that contains more than one contract

Tags: contract-development, truffle, truffle-migration

Suppose my contract named "B" look like :

```
contract A {
   function abc(){
   ...
   }    
}  
contract B is A {
   function bc(){
   ...
   }  
}
```

then how will be the migration file look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to split each contract in its own file. You can always import dependencies.

A.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;
contract A {
    function abc() {}
}
```

B.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;
import "A.sol";
contract B is A {
    function bc() {}
}
```

Generally you only need to deploy the more specialized contract. In this case B, since it inherits from A.

2_deploy_contracts.js

```
const B = artifacts.require("B.sol");
module.exports = function (deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(B);
}
```

Comment: but I am not able to access the function in contract A from B. Is there anything needed to be added in migration file to link both A and B?

Comment: @sruthi23 If B inherits from A then all functions from A should be also be  available from B. If you have an example where this does not happend let me take a look.